# Junit5 TemporaryFolderExtension dependency

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

(with `<junit.jupiter.version>5.3.1</junit.jupiter.version>`)

When I am trying to use `@ExtendWith(TemporaryFolderExtension.class)`, Intellij is unable to find any source to import it from.
I tried to google, but I cant seem to find what artifact would have it...

Answer (score 3):

Up to version **5.3.2** JUnit 5 does *not*, by itself, provide a `TemporaryFolderExtension` (see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1247)  and you have to resort to a JUnit 5 extension pack called [JUnit Pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org/).

However from version **5.4.0-M1** on a temporary folders extension called [`TempDirectory`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0-M1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/support/io/TempDirectory.html) is provided directly by the `junit-jupiter-api` artifact.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without mentioning the version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, the way our project is structured, we have a main POM file with versions specified, then the sub-modules (in this case, Application module) has the dependencies already listed without mentioning version, so that it can refer to the one in the main POM file.

I guess this is the same as what you meant right?

Comment: @Carmageddon Yes. If you are in IDEA try to reimport all maven projects manually by clicking the tab **Maven Projects** -> **Reimport**